# "$save is not a function" the call works fine, but doesn't execute .then()

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a call that POSTs an array with $save, then executes the callback functions for success or failure. With the following code, the request is performed perfectly and returns a 200, yet the neither callback will execute.

```
var endpoint = "my valid url";
    var myResource = $resource(endpoint, 
                                  {}, 
                                  {saveStuff: {method: 'POST', isArray: true}}).saveStuff(payload);
    
    myResource.$save() //browser console says "myResource.$save is not a function"!
        .then(
            function(response){
               console.log("success");
            },
            function(error){
               console.log("failure");
            }
        )
```

If I remove the "isArray: true"

```
{saveStuff: {method: 'POST'/*, isArray: true*/}}).saveStuff(payload);
```

then I get a 400 (because the endpoint expects an array), but I get "failure" to print to console. Why does "isArray" make the browser thing $save is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to take a different approach

```
MyResource.saveOrderNotes.saveStuff({orderId: $scope.orderId}, payload, 
            function(result, headers){
                console.log("success");
            },
            function(error){
                console.log("failure");
            });
```